# many to many array field in django model

Tags: arrays, django, model, key, field

I'm building a work orders model in django. I'd like to have an array field for parts required with quantities and another array field of parts produced with quantities. The parts would be foreign keys from a model in an inventory app I have already created. From what I've read PostgreSQL won't allow for foreign keys in an array field. so I would need to have a many to many field in a new model. But I'm not sure how to construct that. what would be the best way to go about this?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from inventory.parts.models import partslist

# Create your models here.
class jobs(models.Model):
    jobid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    partsrequired = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.ForeignKey(partslist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        )
    )
    partsproduced = ArrayField(
        ArrayField(
            models.ForeignKey(partslist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        )

class instruction(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(jobs)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
class Job(models.Model):
    jobid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    partsrequired = models.ManyToManyField(partslist, related_name='required_for_jobs')
    partsproduced = models.ManyToManyField(partslist, related_name='produced_for_jobs')
```